# Exponential number to long value in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to convert a string representing an exponential number to a long value. Anyone having any ideas how can I do this conversion in Objective-C?

My exponential number is "9.91350253E8"

Comment: Is this "number" a string?

Comment: what datatype you have used for this exponential number ? i.e string or else ?

Comment: see apple doc https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @borrrden :It is a string...

Comment: In that case, go with Ashim's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"9.91350253E8";
NSDictionary    *l = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"." forKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator];
NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:str locale:l];
NSLog(@"%lld", [number longLongValue]);
```

Try this.

Comment: Good answer!  The only thing to be careful of is that this will fail depending on your geographical region.  For example, in France `NSDecimalNumber` will expect a comma instead of a period.  To get around this, you should use the version that specifies a locale also.

Comment: added the locale in an edit .... it is mainly `NSDictionary    *l = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"." forKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator];`

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this -

> NSString *str=@"9.91350253E8";
>
> long  temp = str.longLongValue ;
>
> NSLog(@"long-%ld",temp);

Comment: Have you tested this?  I believe it will return "9" because it is not clever enough to convert from this format.

Comment: @borrrden - yes, it returns 9. The long value should be 9 as it returns

Comment: No, the long value should be 991350253.  See -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

Comment: -1, definitely a wrong answer.